g++ cannot find .lib file despite providing correct path
I'm trying to compile a C++ project using g++ on Windows, but I keep getting the following error:

cannot find -ltoncryptolib: No such file or directory

My command:
g++ -Wall -I"C:/LIB_DIR/ton-compress-contest-windows/toncryptolib-win/include/common" \
-I"C:/LIB_DIR/ton-compress-contest-windows/toncryptolib-win/include/tdutils" \
-I"C:/LIB_DIR/ton-compress-contest-windows/toncryptolib-win/include" \
-I"C:/LIB_DIR/ton-compress-contest-windows/toncryptolib-win/include/crypto" \
-I"C:/LIB_DIR/ton-compress-contest-windows/toncryptolib-win/include/ton" \
"D:/coding/C++/compressor_example.cpp" -o "D:/coding/C++/compressor_example.exe" \
-L"C:/LIB_DIR/ton-compress-contest-windows/toncryptolib-win" -ltoncryptolib

error screenshot
The .lib file exists at C:/LIB_DIR/ton-compress-contest-windows/toncryptolib-win/toncryptolib.lib, but the linker still can't find it.

.lib files are used by the Microsoft C++ compiler. Libraries for GCC are named like libname.a. In your case it should be a file named libtoncryptolib.a. You need to download (or build) the library for the right compiler (look for a MinGW section on the libraries download page).

I recommend either not using g++ on Windows, or not using Windows for g++.  The choice depends on which one of those is your favorite.  If it were up to me, I'd switch from Windows to Unix.
